# MongoDB array of objects update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update array of user information objects in mongoose.
I've stored the user core information in the login process, I want to update some of user information when user tries to make an order.
Here is the code for the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber',
    },

    info: [
      { country: String },
      { city: String },
      { address: String },
      { phone: String },
      { birthdate: Date },
      { gender: { type: String, enum: ['Male', 'Female'] } },
    ],
    //   wishlist: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

In my controller I'm getting the data from front-end react app as JSON format, I want to push some data to info which is an array of objects in the users model above.

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  // Here I constract the data
  const { plan, service, fullName, country, city, address } = req.body.order;
  const { user_id } = req.body;

  // This the method I tried
  try {
    const user = await User.updateOne(
      {
        _id: user_id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          'info.$.country': country,
          'info.$.city': city,
          'info.$.address': address,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    if (user) {
      console.log('USER UPDATED', user);
      res.json(user);
    } else {
      res.json((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    const newOrder = await new Order({
      orderPlan: plan,
      orderService: service,
      orderUser: user_id,
    }).save();
    console.log(newOrder);
    console.log(req.body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I tired other solutions like

```
 const user = await User.updateOne(
      {
        _id: user_id,

        info: { $elemMatch: { country, city, address } },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

So do I need to reformat my model or there is a way to update this array of objects?

Comment: Why info is an array? Why not a plain object with properties?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { $set: { "info.$[i].country": "a1" }} ,
  { arrayFilters: [ { "i.country": "a" } ] }
)
```

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/UMxdpyiKpa9

---

**Option 2**

- if you know the index

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/41S7qs6cYPT

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "info.0.country": "a1",
    "info.1.city": "b1",
    "info.2.address": "c1",
    "info.3.phone": "d1"
  }
})
```

---

Suggestions -

- Change info schema to object instead of an array